# Optimize grid view loading for large amount of data during windows form load

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, datagridview

I have a **grid view(G1) with scroll** which has large amount of data(in rows) in my windows application. Each row in this grid , load two separates grid . During form load , when the grid (G1) gets loaded , it takes huge time for loading because it also loads its related data(data for other grids).

Can anyone suggest me some good way to handle this loading and reduce the loading time and increase its application performance.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is way by making it lazy loading but since i have scrolling functionality in my grid I am unable to find a way out.